# How to handle checkbox controls in windows installer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create a setup project. I want to create a file which will contain values of the checkboxes which are selected by user during installation. How and where to write the code for the same? I am new to windows installer. 
Please provide me pointers for the same.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by saving checkbox values to file ? you want to simply save selected values to a textfile ?

Comment: Yes, I simply want to save selected values to text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do it with installer class.

1. First of add installer class to your setup project. Go to `Add` >
   `Add New Item` > `Select Installer class`

[image: Installer Class]

2. Create a Window Form with radio button to get user input and logic to save selected values to a text file.
3. Within installer class`s Install method open windows form to get the user input. So during the installation windows form will pop up where user can select the values.(*Please not that this form will not open as a modal pop up*)

`Install()`

```
 public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);

            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
```

**Best approach**

Best approach to get the user input during the installation is to create `.wid` file. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913901/how-to-add-additional-custom-window-to-vs-setup-projects-ui-flow/19220436#19220436).

Comment: But I am not able to add InstallerClass to my setup project with the process you told me. I tried to google it  but I don't have any option such "Add new item" which will add classes. Do I need to change any setting?

Comment: @AparnaSavant Just right click on the project and go to add item, its like how you add a class to a project.

Comment: Sorry, but after clicking right button on Project, I am able to see following options under "Add": "Project Output", "File", "Merge Module", "Assembly". There is no "Add Item" option which will eventually lead me to "Installer CLass". Please guide me what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Add a new C# class library project, Right click on it and select Add > New Item > Select Visual C# items > Installer Class.

Comment: +1 to AccessDenied. He's done a lot of work to help you out, Aparna. Upvoting his work or marking it as an answer is his only reward for helping.

Comment: @AccessDenied I did as per your instructions. I am able to compile my project successfully. But while installing my application I am having an error as "Error 1001: FileLoadException error..." In debug log I am able to see an error as "Error 2835:  The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog" Also I am having " Error 2826:  Control Control372 on dialog CustomCheckD extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels"
error for many dialogs. CAn you please help me on this?

Comment: @AparnaSavant Are you using windows installer ? or InstallShield ? Are you using any custom control ?

Comment: I am using Windows installer and custom actions.

Comment: I have created a an extra checkbox by editing .wid file using Orca.