# Password Verification from database for an installation of setup file in Windows forms application

Tags: c#

My Requirement is to create a setup for Windows application. I need to add a form which validates entered password from database. On valid Password setup installation should proceed else setup installation should stop. I am using visual studio 2010.

I have searched a lot of stuff but none of it helped me to meet the requirement. I have added installer class also to verify form. I have also selected user interface and selected textbox but how do I verify textbox value from database. I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537248/showing-custom-form-before-installation), but still I am not able to get exact solution.

Comment: Please share with us what you have done so far.

Comment: i have created setup of my application. during creation i have added files like applicationname.sln ,applicationname.exe. after that I  choose a userinterface in which selected an add dialogue in which  selected textbox but i have stucked how to verify that  value and proceed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

**Please include code and output as content for your question**, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: Trademark capitalization; grammar; noise reduction.