# How to Configure and Validate Serial key in Installshield 2010 premier

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installshield, setup-deployment, license-key

I am deploying my project and want to know how to use serial keys and how to validate them when using InstallShield 2010.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I have provided an answer, and a link to a more detailed answer. However, I am not entirely sure what you are asking due to lacking details in your question. Please try to improve your questions and provide more details in the future, or for the current issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is generally to deal with your license keys in the application itself, unless you want it written to HKLM instead of HKCU - in which case you need the temporary admin rights generally acquired during installation.

The application features more flexibility and control of the process of registering your license key, and crucially an easy way to run the process again.

I have described this issue previously in more detail: [Reasons to deal with licensing in the application rather than the setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24360658/129130).