# Wix custom action is failed to load the dll file?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I am trying to do a custom action at the time of msi installation. But the dll required for my custom action is depends on other dlls. At the time of installtion it is giving the error like "a dll required for this install to complete could not run".How can I load the dependent dll files for this custom action to run properly.

The code that I am using is

```
<CustomAction Id='CheckingPID' BinaryKey='CheckPID' DllEntry='ValidateKey' />
<Binary Id ='CheckPID' SourceFile='$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\LicenseKeyClient_32d.dll'/>
<Binary Id ='CheckPID2' SourceFile='$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\curllib.dll'/>
<Binary Id ='CheckPID3' SourceFile='$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\libsasl.dll'/>
<Binary Id ='CheckPID4' SourceFile='$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\openldap.dll'/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The files that you add in binary table usually get extracted with temporary names during the installation, so your DLL will not be able to locate the other DLLs you add next to it.

A workaround is to add those DLLs as normal files in the Temp system folder and delete them when the installation ends. This has the limitation that you need to set your custom action as deferred, so it executes after the files are installed, thus your DLLs get copied to Temp folder.

I don't know if wix has a support for [temporary files](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/temp-files.html), similar with the one present in Advanced Installer, but if not you could try to write a custom action to simulate it. Basically what Advanced Installer does is to extract those files in the Temp folder the moment the MSI is launched, and also deletes them when the installation is complete. This has the advantage that you can use the temporary files and in immediate custom actions, i.e. well before the files from your package are installed.

Comment: The "usual" nasty way to do that is to stream them from the binary table so they don't need installing and removing. I also suspect it's the user's temp folder, not the system one.

Answer (score 2):

Despite **Bogdan's** excellent answer, allow me to add my 2 cents:

It looks like you are dealing with some form of **license key validation**? The best way is generally to deal with your license keys in the application itself, unless you want it written to **HKLM** instead of **HKCU** - in which case you might need the temporary admin rights generally acquired during installation.

You can also open a HKLM key for writing during setup, and write it from the application though this is generally frowned upon security-wise. This allows you to write a single license key for all users directly from the application.

**The application** features more **flexibility** and **control** of the process of registering your license key, and **crucially an easy way to run the process again**. From my perspective this is almost always needed for a serious application - often due to **trial versions** with the eventual need to register the license key at the end of the trial period from within the application itself - instead of uninstalling the application and reinstalling, or running the setup in repair / maintenance mode - which seems extremely clunky.

I have described this issue previously in some more detail: [Reasons to deal with licensing in the application rather than the setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24360658/129130).

Answer (score 0):

I'll also add that  WiX DTF .NET custom actions really simplify this problem by allowing you to embed content into the self extracting custom action package and make them available in the current directory at runtime.  Very easy.

But yes, Glytzhkof is correct.  Any licensing / DRM done inside of an MSI is easily defeated.  It's best to do this in the app or both.   For example I've worked at companies where it's a share responsibility.  You can enter one now or later.  I've also worked at companies where the license key had bits embedded in it that drove feature selection.   It gets complicated fast so try not to have to go down that road.