# wix custom action database transfer timeout

Tags: sql, wix, custom-action, wix3.11

Wix installer custom action runs a SQL script to transfer data from old database to new. But the script will time out on larger databases. It doesn't timeout when run manually on Management Studio. Is there a way to lengthen the timeout to 20 minutes?

If not, my backup plan is to break up the script into smaller chunks.

Comment: Can you do this from within your application (if any), instead of inside the setup?

Comment: Yes we can, but we can also just run the script in management studios.  We are trying to eliminate work.  

This did give me an idea, create a separate application that runs inside the setup.

Comment: Custom actions are very difficult for a number of reasons. [Here is a short summary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507479/129130), and would you know, [here is a whole rant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46179779/129130). Essentially: try to put it in the application, you will save yourself some serious blues and you will be in a familiar context for debugging?

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer if you like? So others can see how you solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks Stein, I haven't solved it yet, but I'm close to getting it to work through an application.

Comment: Update, putting the SQL into an application solved the issue.

Comment: Great, that always helps to get deployment simpler and application launch and configuration more "interactive". Good luck with all the testing. "*The last meter is long*". Gets tiresome.