# Wix bundle splash screen displays only for fraction of second

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.6, wix3.11

I added splash screen into bundle. On certain machines splash screen displays for ~3 seconds but on few machines it just flashes (less than a second) and launches the welcome screen.

```
<Bundle Name="MyApp" 
      Version="6.0.0.0" 
      Manufacturer="MyOrganisation" 
      UpgradeCode="eaf358e7-be06-48b9-a6d5-89d9b4da6932" 
      SplashScreenSourceFile="images/SplashOriginal.bmp" 
      IconSourceFile="images/logo.ico" >
```

I expect splash screen stays for few seconds on all machines but its not behaving the same way.

Comment: Are the machines that flash the screen very fast machines? With extra good hardware?

Comment: Yes Stein, My Dev Machine is 32 GB Ram, I7 processor @ 2.71 Ghz. whereas other machines where splashscreen appears for ~3 seconds, the configuration is much lower comparitively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Rob Mensching***: Here is the WiX creator Rob Mensching himself on the issue (WiX mailing list):
>   http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Wix-3-6-Burn-SplashScreenSourceFile-Flashes-td6951793.html
>
> ***Managed BA***: I wouldn't really recommend a managed BA (bootstrapper application) for a **`setup.exe`**. You get a dependency
>   on the .NET framework that I don't like.

---

> ***Short***: The below turned into a speech: the gist of it: setup GUI is
>   overrated. Focus on the application launch instead? For corporate deployment setup GUI is never seen or used - everything is silently deployed. Hence the futility of advance setup GUI?

---

***Need-For-Speed***: **`1)`** Setups that are over before they have begun is a new problem in the age of NVMe disks and improved computer I/O and broadband Internet. I think this is one more reason to simplify the GUI in your setup. There are several other reasons: **`2)`** [licensing is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359248/installer-with-online-registration-for-windows-application/24360658#24360658) (of what you should avoid in a setup), **`3)`** GUI bugs is another, **`4)`** the complicated debugging of setups as opposed to applications is important (complexities: conditioning, sequencing, impersonation, debugger connection, etc...), **`5)`** and the fact that GUI is normally suppressed for corporate deployment (**silent installation**), and there are further reasons such as **`6)`** limited GUI feature set, **`7)`** testing is hard, localization is hard, etc...

***Advice***: I would just focus on getting files installed instead - for all these reasons and more. *`If you never get the application installed properly, the user can never use or test out your software for purchase. Expensive mistake.`* You can do a lot during your application launch - including showing the image you refer to for as long as you want with full control with use of normal debugging approaches for applications. I would do that instead of hacking your setup too much.

***Online Help***: You could open a web-page where this image of yours is prominent - from the setup or your application - and you can keep help material there for the user to check at their own pace. It can also be updated on the server and maintained. *`I always harass people with this suggestion :-)`* - and the reasons are many - especially that errors in help material can cause a lot of re-work to re-deploy a software when it is better to keep the content online for maintenance and to make the setup lean and mean.

---

***All time C++ allusion***:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

***New Motto***: Setups be lean and mean.